# SharePoint 2007 List column name with different display name

Tags: sharepoint

I'm very new to using SharePoint. I have created a custom list that I use as a linked table in Access. As the access database pre-existed, i need the column names in my SharePoint List to match those that are in the Access Database, otherwise all my Reports & Queries etc will not work.

Is there a way to have a separate  display name for the columns in my SharePoint List.

For example, the column names are currently like "Innov_Desc", which isn't User friendly. When the users are adding "New Items", I need to display "Description" for example.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to do this change from the the user interface (from settings), I'm afraid it's impossible. You will have to do this change in the code.

Please check the links below to get general idea of what is involve when naming columns:

- [Finding the internal name and display name for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column)
- [SharePoint Column/Field Display Names vs Internal Names](http://salaudeen.blogspot.fi/2011/06/sharepoint-columnfield-display-names-vs.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the display name to something more user friendly via the UI after the column has been created. The internal name of the column will remain whatever it was at the point of creation.